# How to improve Rxjs expression?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

```
save(): void {
 combineLatest(this.selectedSorting$, this.selectedFilters$)
                .pipe(
                    map((data) => {
                        let obj = {};
                        if (data[0]) {
                            obj['filters'] = data[0];
                        }
    
                        if (data[1]) {
                            obj['sorting'] = data[1];
                        }
    
                        return obj;
                    }),
                )
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                });

}
```

I observe two problems:

1. Dirty a map operator
2. Problem with undefined or null observables `this.selectedSorting$, this.selectedFilters$`
3. When any of observers are changed it has effect to `save()`

How to improve it?

As result I expect one object from:

```
{filters: []}
{sorting: []}
{filters: [], sorting: []}
```

My full code:

```
public selectedFilters$ = new Observable();
public selectedSorting$ = new Observable();
public filterButtonDisabled$: Observable<any>;
public setttings$ = new Observable();

@ViewChildren(FilterComponent) filtersList: QueryList<FilterComponent>;

constructor(private settingsService: SettingsService, private applicationService: ApplicationService) {}

public saveSettings(): void {
    this.setttings$.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
}

public resetFilter(): void {
    this.filtersList.forEach((flt) => flt.reset());
}

public doFilter(): void {
    this.selectedFilters$.pipe(switchMap((data) => this.applicationService.filterExecutionApplications(data))).subscribe();
}

public onSorting(sorted: any) {
    this.selectedSorting$ = of(sorted);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selectedFilters$ = combineLatest(...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.changeFilter.pipe(filter((data) => !!data))));
    this.selectedFilters$.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
    this.setttings$ = combineLatest(this.selectedSorting$, this.selectedFilters$).pipe(
        map((data) => ({ filters: data[1], sorting: data[0] })),
    );
}
```

I have tried to get last chnages from `this.selectedSorting$` and `this.selectedFilters$` and call save method. But only when user click over buttons and calls  `public saveSettings(): void {}`

Comment: So you want to
1. Clean map operator
2. Don't want to emit null or undefined observables from 
                    `this.selectedSorting$, this.selectedFilters$`
3. You don't want to create new observable when ever you hit save ?

And you are expecting any of the three result objects that you provided.?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: I have published whole my code

Comment: Are you using Angular ?

Comment: Yes, I use Angular

Comment: Could i USE ` this.selectedSorting$ = of(sorted);` in `combineLatest`?

Comment: So, When ever you sort in the template, `onSorting` function is called with `sorted` parameters ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216728/discussion-between-bharat1226-and-jessy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I understand right what you want?
And can this help you?

```
save(): void {
  combineLatest(this.selectedSorting$, this.selectedFilters$)
     .pipe(
        map((data) => {
           let obj = {
              filters: [],
              sorting: []
           };

           obj.filters = data[0] || [];
           obj.sorting = data[1] || [];
                       
           return obj;
        }),
    ).subscribe((response) => {
         console.log(response);
    });

}
```

or

```
save(): void {
  combineLatest(
     this.selectedSorting$.pipe(map(response => response || [])),
     this.selectedFilters$.pipe(map(response => response || []))
    ).pipe(
        map((data) => {
           return {
              filters: data[0],
              sorting: data[1]
           };
        }),
    ).subscribe((response) => {
         console.log(response);
    });

}
```

Comment: Problemn is that I get data from child from Output here: `public onSorting(sorted: any) {
        this.selectedSorting$ = of(sorted);
    }` And I try to convert data to observer to use it in save method, where I try to combine two observers and get latest values from each other

Comment: If I understand right you can use `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` instead of observable? what do you think?